# CSS Style inheritance/overloading

Tags: css, inheritance, stylesheet

I have a web page that, at a certain point, displays a navigation bar which is nothing more than a list (*ul*) of *a* elements. Most of the style rules for said *a* elements is common. The only part that should change is the image to show which can be guessed from the *id* tag of each *li* element of the list.

So here's the question:

Is there a way in CSS to define a something like a "base" style for all the *a* elements and then set the  image depending on the id? Maybe not ([CSS Control Inheritance - Inheriting Other Control Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641217/css-control-inheritance-inheriting-other-control-styles)) but I'd like to be certain.

I tried:

```
#nav li a {
    /*This would be the 'base' For all the "a"s inside a 
      list inside an element with id=nav (nav -> navigation)*/
 background-color: transparent;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0 -58px;
 border-left: thin #444444 solid;
}


#nav li#settings a {
 background: url(../images/nav_settings.png);
}

#nav li#media a {
 background: url(../images/nav_media.png);
}

#nav li#user a {
 background: url(../images/nav_admin.png);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work... The "base" style is overwritten...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your particular situation, use the background-image CSS directive. When you use background you're resetting all of the previously set background-* properties.

Like this - Example:

```
#nav li#settings a {
 background-image: url(../images/nav_settings.png);
}

#nav li#media a {
 background-image: url(../images/nav_media.png);
}

#nav li#user a {
 background-image: url(../images/nav_admin.png);
}
```

Comment: This is *the* answer. `background: url(../images/nav_settings.png);` should be `background-image: url(../images/nav_settings.png);`

Comment: I agree completely this is the answer.

Comment: Yuuup... I just realized... (Well... It was Firebug who made me realize) I was going to reply to myself, but you guys are really quick!! :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a "base", or default, value for any tag. In your case, you should use the id's on the anchors instead of the parent tags:

a#user, etc.

And, as stated by John, use background-image instead of background for the anchors, because setting background sets all of the background's properties (background-repeat, background-color, etc.)

Comment: Using #parentDiv a is not good practice if you have multiple tags, like in a navigation hierarchy. If each anchor is going to have a different image, why not identify each anchor with its own ID and set the styles there?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... Yeah, right... I'm going to do that too... Actually, that may be a great idea :) It may simplify the underlying JQuery